# json data to treeview javascript

Tags: javascript, json, treeview

Please help me out to create treeview by javascript array. The scenario is I want to create treeview with reverse level. For Example:

```
var arr = [{
            "ID": 1,
            "Phone": "(403) 125-2552",
            "City": "Coevorden",
            "Name": "Grady"
        }, {
            "ID": 2,
            "Phone": "(979) 486-1932",
            "City": "Chełm",
            "Name": "Scarlet"
        }, {
            "ID": 3,
            "Phone": "(573) 685-8350",
            "City": "Wardha",
            "Name": "Adria"
        }, {
            "ID": 4,
            "parentID": 3,
            "Phone": "(630) 292-9737",
            "City": "Villers-la-Loue",
            "Name": "Xerxes"
        }, {
            "ID": 5,
            "Phone": "(755) 968-6539",
            "City": "Gönen",
            "Name": "Madeson"
        }, {
            "ID": 6,
            "parentID": 5,
            "Phone": "(644) 892-5485",
            "City": "Timkur",
            "Name": "Rae"
        }, {
            "ID": 7,
            "Phone": "(896) 297-6568",
            "City": "Louvain-la-Neuve",
            "Name": "Celeste"
        }, {
            "ID": 8,
            "parentID": 5,
            "Phone": "(168) 452-3538",
            "City": "Worksop",
            "Name": "Rowan"
        }, {
            "ID": 9,
            "parentID": 5,
            "Phone": "(873) 337-9560",
            "City": "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler",
            "Name": "Kendall"
        }, {
            "ID": 10,
            "Phone": "(450) 579-0491",
            "City": "MIDdelburg",
            "Name": "Madaline"
        }, {
            "ID": 11,
            "Phone": "(111) 162-2502",
            "City": "Birecik",
            "Name": "Chandler"
        }, {
            "ID": 12,
            "parentID": 8,
            "Phone": "(712) 483-3905",
            "City": "Courbevoie",
            "Name": "Craig"
        }, {
            "ID": 13,
            "parentID": 8,
            "Phone": "(872) 499-5833",
            "City": "Cuccaro Vetere",
            "Name": "Basia"
        }, {
            "ID": 14,
            "parentID": 6,
            "Phone": "(724) 797-0077",
            "City": "Portree",
            "Name": "Elmo"
        }, {
            "ID": 15,
            "parentID": 5,
            "Phone": "(366) 967-0433",
            "City": "Dublin",
            "Name": "Cairo"
        }, {
            "ID": 16,
            "parentID": 11,
            "Phone": "(147) 708-7321",
            "City": "Rivière-du-Loup",
            "Name": "Mannix"
        }, {
            "ID": 17,
            "Phone": "(407) 519-9894",
            "City": "Roubaix",
            "Name": "Justine"
        }, {
            "ID": 18,
            "parentID": 14,
            "Phone": "(938) 793-5446",
            "City": "Eugene",
            "Name": "Dahlia"
        }, {
            "ID": 19,
            "parentID": 5,
            "Phone": "(425) 682-2189",
            "City": "Salisbury",
            "Name": "Irene"
        }, {
            "ID": 20,
            "parentID": 12,
            "Phone": "(351) 187-8200",
            "City": "Garaguso",
            "Name": "Trevor"
        }, {
            "ID": 21,
            "Phone": "(601) 944-5214",
            "City": "Pointe-au-Pic",
            "Name": "Iris"
        }, {
            "ID": 22,
            "parentID": 20,
            "Phone": "(479) 532-6127",
            "City": "Salt Lake City",
            "Name": "Fleur"
        }, {
            "ID": 23,
            "parentID": 19,
            "Phone": "(339) 973-1695",
            "City": "Meldert",
            "Name": "Hayley"
        }, {
            "ID": 24,
            "parentID": 11,
            "Phone": "(946) 766-1649",
            "City": "Corral",
            "Name": "Baker"
        }, {
            "ID": 25,
            "Phone": "(964) 413-7033",
            "City": "Joliet",
            "Name": "Leo"
        }, {
            "ID": 26,
            "parentID": 7,
            "Phone": "(898) 476-0059",
            "City": "Burntisland",
            "Name": "Rigel"
        }, {
            "ID": 27,
            "parentID": 21,
            "Phone": "(163) 267-0914",
            "City": "Lac Ste. Anne",
            "Name": "Scarlett"
        }, {
            "ID": 28,
            "parentID": 10,
            "Phone": "(486) 637-9167",
            "City": "San Maurizio Canavese",
            "Name": "Wang"
        }, {
            "ID": 29,
            "parentID": 20,
            "Phone": "(268) 646-0066",
            "City": "Palermo",
            "Name": "Eagan"
        }, {
            "ID": 30,
            "parentID": 2,
            "Phone": "(641) 756-7073",
            "City": "Harrison Hot Springs",
            "Name": "Hamilton"
        }, {
            "ID": 31,
            "parentID": 26,
            "Phone": "(820) 709-1328",
            "City": "Ottignies",
            "Name": "Liberty"
        }, {
            "ID": 32,
            "parentID": 12,
            "Phone": "(915) 642-4154",
            "City": "Bihain",
            "Name": "Noel"
        }, {
            "ID": 33,
            "parentID": 27,
            "Phone": "(137) 830-3127",
            "City": "Kapuskasing",
            "Name": "AIDan"
        }, {
            "ID": 34,
            "parentID": 31,
            "Phone": "(594) 856-4377",
            "City": "Buin",
            "Name": "Murphy"
        }, {
            "ID": 35,
            "parentID": 28,
            "Phone": "(951) 871-5461",
            "City": "Gold Coast",
            "Name": "Ila"
        }, {
            "ID": 36,
            "parentID": 10,
            "Phone": "(781) 305-7685",
            "City": "Castel Maggiore",
            "Name": "Katelyn"
        }, {
            "ID": 37,
            "parentID": 10,
            "Phone": "(716) 572-8734",
            "City": "Chapecó",
            "Name": "Logan"
        }, {
            "ID": 38,
            "parentID": 28,
            "Phone": "(214) 619-7252",
            "City": "Stargard Szczeciński",
            "Name": "Adria"
        }, {
            "ID": 39,
            "parentID": 10,
            "Phone": "(422) 223-5912",
            "City": "Bad Vöslau",
            "Name": "Katell"
        }, {
            "ID": 40,
            "parentID": 2,
            "Phone": "(921) 336-7339",
            "City": "Namur",
            "Name": "Lionel"
        }, {
            "ID": 41,
            "parentID": 28,
            "Phone": "(386) 567-5819",
            "City": "Borchtlombeek",
            "Name": "Erin"
        }, {
            "ID": 42,
            "parentID": 8,
            "Phone": "(308) 835-2758",
            "City": "Alto del Carmen",
            "Name": "Austin"
        }, {
            "ID": 43,
            "parentID": 2,
            "Phone": "(410) 695-8540",
            "City": "Saint-Laurent",
            "Name": "Deanna"
        }, {
            "ID": 44,
            "parentID": 4,
            "Phone": "(287) 866-8953",
            "City": "Fiuminata",
            "Name": "Darius"
        }, {
            "ID": 45,
            "parentID": 14,
            "Phone": "(329) 372-0345",
            "City": "Laurencekirk",
            "Name": "Kelsey"
        }, {
            "ID": 46,
            "parentID": 12,
            "Phone": "(566) 705-6690",
            "City": "Lunel",
            "Name": "Skyler"
        }, {
            "ID": 47,
            "parentID": 44,
            "Phone": "(779) 411-0381",
            "City": "Pontedera",
            "Name": "Harding"
        }, {
            "ID": 48,
            "parentID": 18,
            "Phone": "(393) 562-0884",
            "City": "WIDooie",
            "Name": "Marny"
        }, {
            "ID": 49,
            "parentID": 28,
            "Phone": "(299) 937-4358",
            "City": "Zamora",
            "Name": "Brennan"
        }, {
            "ID": 50,
            "parentID": 35,
            "Phone": "(474) 337-2674",
            "City": "Hazaribag",
            "Name": "Lance"
        }]
```

and I'm trying to create a tree view in the following order:
Expected output for example:

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Phone": "(403) 125-2552",
        "City": "Coevorden",
        "Name": "Grady"
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Phone": "(979) 486-1932",
        "City": "Chełm",
        "Name": "Scarlet",
        "children": [
            {
                "ID": 30,
                "parentID": 2,
                "Phone": "(641) 756-7073",
                "City": "Harrison Hot Springs",
                "Name": "Hamilton",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 54,
                        "parentID": 30,
                        "Phone": "(800) 876-5942",
                        "City": "Ribnitz-Damgarten",
                        "Name": "Kelsie",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "ID": 62,
                                "parentID": 54,
                                "Phone": "(523) 159-2911",
                                "City": "Biała Podlaska",
                                "Name": "Clio"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 87,
                        "parentID": 30,
                        "Phone": "(500) 895-9220",
                        "City": "Piracicaba",
                        "Name": "Maya"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": 40,
                "parentID": 2,
                "Phone": "(921) 336-7339",
                "City": "Namur",
                "Name": "Lionel"
            },
            {
                "ID": 43,
                "parentID": 2,
                "Phone": "(410) 695-8540",
                "City": "Saint-Laurent",
                "Name": "Deanna",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 63,
                        "parentID": 43,
                        "Phone": "(475) 190-5102",
                        "City": "Nicoya",
                        "Name": "Nola"
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 98,
                        "parentID": 43,
                        "Phone": "(268) 572-5059",
                        "City": "San Marcello Pistoiese",
                        "Name": "Marny"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Phone": "(573) 685-8350",
        "City": "Wardha",
        "Name": "Adria",
        "children": [
            {
                "ID": 4,
                "parentID": 3,
                "Phone": "(630) 292-9737",
                "City": "Villers-la-Loue",
                "Name": "Xerxes",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "ID": 44,
                        "parentID": 4,
                        "Phone": "(287) 866-8953",
                        "City": "Fiuminata",
                        "Name": "Darius",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "ID": 47,
                                "parentID": 44,
                                "Phone": "(779) 411-0381",
                                "City": "Pontedera",
                                "Name": "Harding",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "ID": 92,
                                        "parentID": 47,
                                        "Phone": "(925) 263-0254",
                                        "City": "Curacaví",
                                        "Name": "Aristotle"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "ID": 56,
                        "parentID": 4,
                        "Phone": "(963) 719-2718",
                        "City": "Gore",
                        "Name": "Rafael"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ID": 58,
                "parentID": 3,
                "Phone": "(464) 318-7548",
                "City": "Curepto",
                "Name": "Leila"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I gave this output as an example. What can I do to get my data output like this?

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried so  far.

Comment: I added the code I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a stadard approach with a single loop, an object for collecting and dynamic keys for `ID` and `parentID`.

```js
const
    getTree = (array, root, key, parent) => array.reduce((t, o) => {
        [[o[parent], {}], ['children', []]]
            .reduce((o, [k, v]) => o[k] = o[k] || v, t)
            .push(Object.assign(t[o[key]] = t[o[key]] || {}, o));
        return t;
    }, {})[root].children,
    data = [{ ID: 1, Phone: "(403) 125-2552", City: "Coevorden", Name: "Grady" }, { ID: 2, Phone: "(979) 486-1932", City: "Chełm", Name: "Scarlet" }, { ID: 3, Phone: "(573) 685-8350", City: "Wardha", Name: "Adria" }, { ID: 4, parentID: 3, Phone: "(630) 292-9737", City: "Villers-la-Loue", Name: "Xerxes" }, { ID: 5, Phone: "(755) 968-6539", City: "Gönen", Name: "Madeson" }, { ID: 6, parentID: 5, Phone: "(644) 892-5485", City: "Timkur", Name: "Rae" }, { ID: 7, Phone: "(896) 297-6568", City: "Louvain-la-Neuve", Name: "Celeste" }, { ID: 8, parentID: 5, Phone: "(168) 452-3538", City: "Worksop", Name: "Rowan" }, { ID: 9, parentID: 5, Phone: "(873) 337-9560", City: "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", Name: "Kendall" }, { ID: 10, Phone: "(450) 579-0491", City: "MIDdelburg", Name: "Madaline" }, { ID: 11, Phone: "(111) 162-2502", City: "Birecik", Name: "Chandler" }, { ID: 12, parentID: 8, Phone: "(712) 483-3905", City: "Courbevoie", Name: "Craig" }, { ID: 13, parentID: 8, Phone: "(872) 499-5833", City: "Cuccaro Vetere", Name: "Basia" }, { ID: 14, parentID: 6, Phone: "(724) 797-0077", City: "Portree", Name: "Elmo" }, { ID: 15, parentID: 5, Phone: "(366) 967-0433", City: "Dublin", Name: "Cairo" }, { ID: 16, parentID: 11, Phone: "(147) 708-7321", City: "Rivière-du-Loup", Name: "Mannix" }, { ID: 17, Phone: "(407) 519-9894", City: "Roubaix", Name: "Justine" }, { ID: 18, parentID: 14, Phone: "(938) 793-5446", City: "Eugene", Name: "Dahlia" }, { ID: 19, parentID: 5, Phone: "(425) 682-2189", City: "Salisbury", Name: "Irene" }, { ID: 20, parentID: 12, Phone: "(351) 187-8200", City: "Garaguso", Name: "Trevor" }, { ID: 21, Phone: "(601) 944-5214", City: "Pointe-au-Pic", Name: "Iris" }, { ID: 22, parentID: 20, Phone: "(479) 532-6127", City: "Salt Lake City", Name: "Fleur" }, { ID: 23, parentID: 19, Phone: "(339) 973-1695", City: "Meldert", Name: "Hayley" }, { ID: 24, parentID: 11, Phone: "(946) 766-1649", City: "Corral", Name: "Baker" }, { ID: 25, Phone: "(964) 413-7033", City: "Joliet", Name: "Leo" }, { ID: 26, parentID: 7, Phone: "(898) 476-0059", City: "Burntisland", Name: "Rigel" }, { ID: 27, parentID: 21, Phone: "(163) 267-0914", City: "Lac Ste. Anne", Name: "Scarlett" }, { ID: 28, parentID: 10, Phone: "(486) 637-9167", City: "San Maurizio Canavese", Name: "Wang" }, { ID: 29, parentID: 20, Phone: "(268) 646-0066", City: "Palermo", Name: "Eagan" }, { ID: 30, parentID: 2, Phone: "(641) 756-7073", City: "Harrison Hot Springs", Name: "Hamilton" }, { ID: 31, parentID: 26, Phone: "(820) 709-1328", City: "Ottignies", Name: "Liberty" }, { ID: 32, parentID: 12, Phone: "(915) 642-4154", City: "Bihain", Name: "Noel" }, { ID: 33, parentID: 27, Phone: "(137) 830-3127", City: "Kapuskasing", Name: "AIDan" }, { ID: 34, parentID: 31, Phone: "(594) 856-4377", City: "Buin", Name: "Murphy" }, { ID: 35, parentID: 28, Phone: "(951) 871-5461", City: "Gold Coast", Name: "Ila" }, { ID: 36, parentID: 10, Phone: "(781) 305-7685", City: "Castel Maggiore", Name: "Katelyn" }, { ID: 37, parentID: 10, Phone: "(716) 572-8734", City: "Chapecó", Name: "Logan" }, { ID: 38, parentID: 28, Phone: "(214) 619-7252", City: "Stargard Szczeciński", Name: "Adria" }, { ID: 39, parentID: 10, Phone: "(422) 223-5912", City: "Bad Vöslau", Name: "Katell" }, { ID: 40, parentID: 2, Phone: "(921) 336-7339", City: "Namur", Name: "Lionel" }, { ID: 41, parentID: 28, Phone: "(386) 567-5819", City: "Borchtlombeek", Name: "Erin" }, { ID: 42, parentID: 8, Phone: "(308) 835-2758", City: "Alto del Carmen", Name: "Austin" }, { ID: 43, parentID: 2, Phone: "(410) 695-8540", City: "Saint-Laurent", Name: "Deanna" }, { ID: 44, parentID: 4, Phone: "(287) 866-8953", City: "Fiuminata", Name: "Darius" }, { ID: 45, parentID: 14, Phone: "(329) 372-0345", City: "Laurencekirk", Name: "Kelsey" }, { ID: 46, parentID: 12, Phone: "(566) 705-6690", City: "Lunel", Name: "Skyler" }, { ID: 47, parentID: 44, Phone: "(779) 411-0381", City: "Pontedera", Name: "Harding" }, { ID: 48, parentID: 18, Phone: "(393) 562-0884", City: "WIDooie", Name: "Marny" }, { ID: 49, parentID: 28, Phone: "(299) 937-4358", City: "Zamora", Name: "Brennan" }, { ID: 50, parentID: 35, Phone: "(474) 337-2674", City: "Hazaribag", Name: "Lance" }],
    tree = getTree(data, undefined, 'ID', 'parentID');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        tree = function(array) {
        var o = {
            ID: 0
        }

        function arrGet(o) {
            if (Array.isArray(o.children)) {
                o.children.forEach(arrGet);
            }
        }
        array.forEach(function(a) {
            o[a.ID] = o[a.ID] || {
                ID: a.ID,
                parentID: a.parentID,
                Phone: a.Phone,
                City: a.City,
                Name: a.Name
            };
            a.children = o[a.ID].children;
            o[a.parentID] = o[a.parentID] || {
                ID: a.parentID
            };
            o[a.parentID].children = o[a.parentID].children || [];
            o[a.parentID].children.push(o[a.ID]);
        });
        arrGet(o[0]);
        return o[0].children;
    }(arr);
console.log('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

I get results with this code, but error returns for objects without parent ID.
I have to manually write parentID = 0 to objects without parentID with this code.

Comment: This is not really an answer but an edit to your question. After you post a question you are able to edit it any time to update clarifications. You should do that with the code in this answer and delete the answer